# Isometric depth sorting issue with big objects

Tags: actionscript-3, sorting, depth, isometric

I'm currently building an as3 isometric game, but I'm having a lot of problem with depth sorting. I've searched for a solution, but didn't found anything that match my problem (rectangle objects).

Here is a screenshot of my game:

[image]

As you can see, depth sorting works well when it's between 1x1 tiles objects. I simply use their x and y coordinates (relative to the isometric map) to sort them.

The problem comes when I have bigger objects, like 2x2 or 1x4 or 4x1.

Any idea how should I handle depth sorting then?

Answer (score 8):

I don't think it is possible to sort a scene based on a single `x`,`y` value for each object if some of them can be long enough that one end should be at a different depth than the other. For instance, consider how you'd handle the rendering if the brown chair in your picture was moved one square down-left (to the square between the blue chair and the long couch). It would be deeper in the scene than the red table behind the couch, but would need to be rendered on top of the couch, which would need to be on top of the table.

I think there are two simple solutions:

- **Design your
  levels using only one sort of overlap for large objects**. For
  instance, you could specify that an object's depth is based on its
  nearest corner, which would require you to avoid putting things in
  front of its most distant bits (since it will render on top of them).
  Or you could stick with your current code (which seems to use the
  most distant corner for depth) and avoid putting anything behind the
  nearer parts. You may still have trouble with characters and other
  objects that move around though. You might be able to make the
  troublesome tiles inaccessible if you're careful with your design,
  but in some cases this may be too restrictive.
- **Break up your large objects into smaller ones
  which would have their own depths**. You will probably want to go right
  down to 1x1 pieces, each of which will have an unambiguous depth. You
  might choose keep the larger objects in the code as invisible
  containers for the smaller pieces, or they could be eliminated
  entirely, whichever makes it easier for you to load up and enable
  interaction with the various bits.

Splitting larger objects in to `1x1` sized pieces can also be nice since you can make them modular. That is, you can build differently sized objects by putting together `1x1` pieces in different combinations. If you cut your `2x1` tables in your image in half vertically, for instance, and created a `1x1` middle tile that fit in between them, you could stretch the design out to `3x1` or `10x1`, depending on how many times you repeat the middle tile. There's a lot of other ways to make tiled graphics look good with only a modest amount of art required.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I surely can't work with the first solution, since it's the user who build his own casino. I can't put him limitations. But the second solution seem interesting, I'll try it see if I can get something to work. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Ultima Online emulators (specifically, POL, though there may be others) achieve this through the implementation and usage of the concept of a 'multi' -- a single object comprised of sections of cut-up larger graphics. These cut-up graphics are such that their sprites are vertically-split at the left- and right-corner points of iso grid boundaries.

Other considerations:
- render 'multi' pieces sorted screen-Y axis from top-to-bottom.
- the southern (i.e. screen bottom-left) component of a 'multi' becomes the anchoring tile position (in the case of your couch, its left-most piece).
- consider that each map location can also hold its own vertical stack of objects; offsetting each object's render by screen-Y simulates height/altitude, and these must be sorted bottom-to-top (e.g. lowest-altitude to highest altitude).

Good luck!